# Error "Failed to connect to mailserver at localhost port 25" after installing userpie

Tags: php, mysql, login-script

I followed every step in the documentation in [the user pie website](http://userpie.com) but i can't get it to work well.

UserPie is an open source Registration and login system, everything worked properly upon installation expect for the part that require sending email to user after registering so as to authenticate the user... Here is the error message i get..

> Am testing on a local server

Here is the error I am getting:

[image: user pie printScreen]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve] detailing your code. Explain why it does not work for you and what the expected results are.